# How to use FLTK 1.1 dll in MinGW?

Tags: dll, mingw, hyperlink, fltk

I am trying to compile a project with MinGW that uses the fltk library. Whenever it gets to the file using fltk, it tells me "cannot find -lfltk".

I know it comes down to getting the .dll for the library and where I put it, but I am having a lot of trouble figuring this out. I found two files in the fltk folder named fltk.lib.dsp and fltkdll.dsp. I tried to just put these files in my system32 folder, but that did not work. I'm guessing thats because these are both VC++ 6 project files and not actually .dll and .lib files. I found this article:

http://www.fltk.org/articles.php?L372+I0+TFAQ+P1+Q

but I don't understand what it is saying.

> you will need to define the FL_DLL preprocessor symbol to get the correct linkage commands embedded within the FLTK header files.

What does that mean? Do I need to `#define` something before my `include`s? How does this sentence translate into code?

If I am not on the right track please tell me. Any help is appreciated.

### edit:

Also, I have my `PATH` variable set to C:\MinGW/bin/. I tried setting the files in there, but that did not work either. I know I have to do something to these .dsp files, but don't know what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the error message is not related to dll.
it  actually says that the linker library named 'libfltk.a' is not found.

so you should have that library first for compiling your program.